# Split a String with Giving each Variable inside it a Value

Tags: c#, string, split, trim

I have this code which is supposed to `Split` and assign a value to each variable inside the `String`:

```
string ab = "Seq [A=255, B=0, C=0, D=0]";

string[] abcd = ab.Split(',');

int a = Convert.ToInt32(abcd[0].Split('=')[1].Trim());
int b = Convert.ToInt32(abcd[1].Split('=')[1].Trim());
int c = Convert.ToInt32(abcd[2].Split('=')[1].Trim());
int d = Convert.ToInt32(abcd[3].Split('=')[1].Trim());
```

On the last line I got this error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: You're splitting by `,` which means abcd[0] will be `Seq [A`, abcd[1] will be `255, B=`, etc. based on your input string.

Comment: In `abcd[3]` you have `"0]"` so what's wrong with this error? Don't you have debugger to look into these variables?

Comment: int d = Convert.ToInt32(abcd[3].Split('=')[1].Split(']')[0].Trim());

Comment: This looks like a job for regex

Comment: you should use `Regex.Split();`  , much cleaner and easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final split leaves the ] in the string. Try:

```
int d = Convert.ToInt32((abcd[3].Substring(0, abcd[3].Length - 1)).Split('=')[1].Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, `Convert.ToInt("0]")` does not seem like a number to me as well. Note how `abcd[3] == " =0]"` in your case.

This is an example where a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  would lead you to smaller and smaller versions until the problem becomes obvious. In your case I would have narrowed it down to:

```
string ab = "Seq [A=255, B=0, C=0, D=0]";
string[] abcd = ab.Split(',');
int d = Convert.ToInt32(abcd[3].Split('=')[1].Trim());
```

then to

```
int d = Convert.ToInt32(" D=0]".Split('=')[1].Trim());
```

and so on, until the error becomes obvious. Once you have mastered the technique you will probably depend on it a lot and find it incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*Regular Expressions* is another approach:

```
  using System.Linq;  
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string ab = "Seq [A=255, B=0, C=0, D=0]";

  Dictionary<string, int> vars = Regex
    .Matches(ab, @"(?<Name>[A-Za-z]+)\s*=\s*(?<Value>-?[0-9]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(match => match.Groups["Name"].Value,
                  match => int.Parse(match.Groups["Value"].Value),
                  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Then

```
  int a = vars["a"];
  int b = vars["b"];

  // Do we have "e" variable?
  if (vars.ContainsKey("e")) {
    ...
  }

  // If we have "d" variable, assign it to d    
  if (var.TryGetValue("d", out int d)) {
    ...
  }
```